# Gitlab+Gitolite on Ubuntu server: why it doesn't work using with windows clients?

Tags: ubuntu, gitolite, gitlab

I was trying to set up gitolite and [GitLab][1] on Ubuntu and it is working. I can clone, push and pull in via `admin@local.host` in Linux. **But it's not working on Windows**.
I created user via GitLab and added ssh key in that user (Windows's user).

When I tried to clone the repository, there was password prompt.
It is like the key on Ubuntu and Windows are not synchronized. I did `chmod: 700- .ssh and 600- authorized_keys` but it's not working. So I don't know what am I missing here.

```
>   [1] OH IMPORTANT! You need to convert putty key into openssh key and
> put it in the account.
```

Comment: Consider posting the question on superuser.com or askubuntu.com for a more fitting audience.

Answer (score 1):

Check on Windows the environment variable `%HOME%`:

It isn't defined by default, and your ssh will need it to find your public and private keys (stored under `%HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)`)

In this case, the [OP Sam Mie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1688895/sam-mie) confirms it was a server address resolution issue:

> I've changed the name of server into ip address like from `git@localhost` into `git@198.xxx.x.x` and it works.

Comment: I've changed the name of server into ip address like from git@localhost into git@198.xxx.x.x and it works.

Comment: @SamMie Excellent. I have added this solution to the answer for more visibility.

Comment: thanks gents. I had a similar issue - windows7 and unable to clone, but from a remote gitlab server. Changing to the server ip address worked for me, after struggling for too long!